# Audio aleatorio na pagina

Tags: php, random, áudio

Queria que sempre quando alguem entrar em uma pagina seja reproduzido algum aldio aleatorio que esteja em uma pasta.

eu tentei usar isso

```
<?php

$dir_path = "data/";
$extensions_array = array('mp3');

if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
    $files = scandir($dir_path);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
    {
        if($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..')
        {

            $file = pathinfo($files[$i]);
            $extension = $file['extension'];


            if(in_array($extension, $extensions_array))
            {

            echo "<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
                 <source src='$dir_path$files[$i]'>
                  </audio> ";



            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Mas entro na pagina ele carrega todos audios de uma vez. Alguem pode me ajudar ?

quando olho o source code aparece todos audios que estao na pasta.

```
<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'> <source src='data/defacee.mp3'></audio>

 <audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'> <source src='data/sound.mp3'> </audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloquei um `shuffle($files);` p escolher um arquivo aleatório antes do for e um `Break;` depois do echo do audio.

```
   <?php

    $dir_path = "data/";
    $extensions_array = array('mp3');

    if(is_dir($dir_path))
    {
        $files = scandir($dir_path);


        shuffle($files);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
        {
            if($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..')
            {

                $file = pathinfo($files[$i]);
                $extension = $file['extension'];


                if(in_array($extension, $extensions_array))
                {

                echo "<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
                     <source src='$dir_path$files[$i]'>
                      </audio> ";

                      Break;



                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para obter todas as musicas você pode utilizar o `glob`, dessa forma:

```
$musicas = glob('data/*.{mp3,wav}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Isto irá listar todos os `.mp3` e `.wav` que estão na pasta `data`, por exemplo:

```
array (
  0 => 'data/07. Alphaverb & Intractable One - Turbulence (FRGMNT_7).mp3',
  1 => 'data/Frontliner - What You Come For (Radio Edit).mp3',
  2 => 'data/Frontliner - Around The World (Extended Mix).wav',
)
```

*Caso utilize outro formato acrescente ele ao *filtro* do `glob`.*

---

Então para escolher uma aleatoriamente seria preferível utilizar um CSPRNG, logo poderia utilizar o `random_int()`, **requer PHP 7+**:

```
<?php

$musicas = glob('data/*.{mp3,wav}', GLOB_BRACE);   

$musica = $musicas[random_int(0, count($musicas) - 1)];

?>

<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
    <source src='<?= $musica ?>'>
</audio>
```

Se não quiser utilizar um CSPRNG pode optar por um Mersenne-twister (o Spotfy utiliza ele, por exemplo) então utilize:

```
<?php

$musicas = glob('data/*.{mp3,wav}', GLOB_BRACE);

$musica = $musicas[mt_rand(0, count($musicas) - 1)];

?>

<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
   <source src='<?= $musica ?>'>
</audio>
```

Se não, pode utilizar o `array_rand`:

```
<?php

$musicas = glob('data/*.{mp3,wav}', GLOB_BRACE);

$musica = $musicas[array_rand($musicas)];

?>

<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
   <source src='<?= $musica ?>'>
</audio>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou. porem eu usei um shuffle($files);  antes do for, e um break; apos o echo do audio

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.random(); para gerar número aleatório no intervalo de 1 até a quantidade de arquivos de áudio que o seu diretório contém, pós isso é só passar esse valor.

```
 echo "<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
                 <source src='$dir_path$files[$numberAleatorio]'>
                  </audio> ";
```

Comment: Ja estou contando a quantidade de arquivos  for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)

Comment: Então é só fazer: rand(1, count($files));

Comment: Algo esta errado, quando olho o source code aparece os dois audios,<audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
                 <source src='data/defacee.mp3'>
                  </audio> <audio loop='loop' autoplay='autoplay'>
                 <source src='data/sound.mp3'>
                  </audio>